# Problem with running an R-Markdown script in R while installing packages. I got an error while trying to knit the output of the document

Tags: r-markdown

First, I have installed the following packages in R-Markdown file
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
When I try to Knit to HTML or Word, I got this error-
*

Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror calls:... withvisible->eval->eval->install.packages->contrib.url
Execution halted*

Your help is appreciated in advance. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the actual ´install.packages´ in your R Markdown file?  You have to either remove that from Rmd code or keep it in a separate chunk, and use `{r eval=FALSE}.`

Comment: Thank you very much. You made my day. It works with {r eval=FALSE}.

Comment: @ViviG, at this time, the plot I created from ggplot is not present in knitr html report when I use { r eval = FALSE} as you suggested. What should I set the plots to be displayed in my output? Thank you.

Comment: You have to have the `install.packages` in a separate chunk in this case. What `eval=FALSE`  does is stopping that chunk from running, while still showing the code. The libraries have to be called. Hope you know what I mean! Otherwise please edit your question with your code so I can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

@ViviG where do I have to put this {r eval=FALSE}?

This is my current query:

### Visualization

You can also embed the visualization, for example:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

ggplot(data=penguins)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=flipper_length_mm,y=body_mass_g,color=species))+
  labs(title = "Palmer Penguins: Body Mass vs. Flipper Length", subtitle = "Sample of Three Penguin Species",
       caption = "Data collected by Dr. Kristen Gorman")+
  annotate("text",x=220,y=4000,label="The Gentoos are the largest",color="blue",fontface="bold",size=4.5,angle=30)
```

Same error displayed after knit-ing

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation points for comments. So here the answer with Maung's question:

Here is the corrected chunk set up:
First set up the installation chunk as follows:

````
```{r, eval = 'FALSE'}
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ggplot2")
install.packages("palmerpenguins")
````

````
Then run the following chunk:


```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(palmerpenguins)

ggplot(data=penguins)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=flipper_length_mm,y=body_mass_g,color=species))+
  labs(title = "Palmer Penguins: Body Mass vs. Flipper Length", subtitle = "Sample of Three Penguin Species", caption = "Data collected by Dr. Kristen Gorman")+
  annotate("text",x = 220,y = 4000,label = "The Gentoos are the largest",color="blue",fontface="bold",size=4.5,angle=30)
````